# Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am getting the above error in my code. I do have the python keras library installed. Can anyone pls help with this?

Comment: are you using those quotes in the file too?

Answer (score 4):

I changed it to -- `from keras.applications import ImageDataGenerator` and Voila it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

I changed `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image` to `keras_preprocessing.image` and solved the issue.

Comment: I was getting this import error when I updated to keras3. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`

This will surely work

Comment: COuld you elaborate?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).